# How to delete a bad trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

On Mysql Version 5.0.77, I ran this

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_trap_to_memory AFTER INSERT on Table1
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO Table1_Copy SELECT NEW.*;
```

It ran, but now the database is disconnecting whenever I try to do certain things:

Can't view triggers-

```
mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE '%'\G
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    7
Current database: mydb

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Can't drop the problem trigger-

```
mysql> DROP TRIGGER ins_trap_to_memory;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Can't query information_schema.TRIGGERS-

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.TRIGGERS;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    12
Current database: information_schema

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Answer (score 2):

Do other types of query work?

It doesn't seem likely to me that the two are related, unless perhaps Table1 has a high volume of inserts going on continuously, and it's the result of server overload. It might just be an intermittent connection issue.

Either way, you should be able to drop it with:

```
DROP TRIGGER ins_trap_to_memory ON Table1
```

Comment: I wasn't able to try this because I found a fix before I saw this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get rid of the bad trigger by going to `/var/lib/mysql/mydb` and deleting `Table1.TRG`.

Comment: what was wrong with that trigger?

Comment: Deleting the trigger that way is a terrible way of managing your MySQL and the messages that server went away are probably symptoms of something far worse than being unable to execute a few queries..

Comment: It was literally impossible to delete the trigger from inside MySQL.